# char* vs const char* as a parameter

Tags: c

There are many times that I get compile errors when I use `char*` instead of `const char*`. So, I am not sure the actual difference, the syntax and the compile mechanism.

Comment: What is your system and compiler?

Comment: *"...I get compile errors..."* **What** compile(r) errors? What does the code look like? What's the signature of the function you're calling? The more effort you put into your question, the better both the quantity and quality of answers you'll get.

Comment: I get the error: 'cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char*' to 'const char*'
'

Comment: @Sunscreen: Can't you post the code?

Comment: @Sunscreen: ...and (quoting) "What does the code look like? What's the signature of the function you're calling?"

Comment: If you're getting compiler **errors** and not warnings, then you should have tagged this as C++ not C. Implicit casts which discard const are not an error in C.

Comment: I read interesting (useful) answers to a legitimate question. It seems to me concise, not too badly explaned, and also enough clear what the user is asking (and in fact, useful answers exist already). So I wonder why the -1. +1 because of this

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you're after the difference between the two, just think of them as:

- **char*** is a pointer that points to a location containing a value of type char that can also be changed. The pointer's value can be changed, i.e. the pointer can be modified to point to different locations.
- **const char*** is a pointer, whose value can be also changed, that points to a location containing a value of type char that **cannot** be changed.

Comment: Though what if I allocate memory to both and then assign?

Comment: @Sunscreen: You'll be able to write to the memory via the `char *` pointer, and not via the `const char *` pointer.

Comment: There are several reasons to use `const char *`. One is that it documents that your code will not be modifying the data pointed to. Another is that it will prevent you from inadvertently (e.g. due to a typo like `=` instead of `==` or typing the wrong variable name) writing somewhere you didn't mean to. And it *may* help the compiler determine optimizations that can be made (but probably not if the compiler is already sufficiently smart).

Comment: @Sunscreen: *"And then, what is the point of using 'const char*' ?"* For me, mostly two reasons: 1. As "R." pointed out, it documents your code, it's part of the contract of your function or whatever. 2. Using a `const char *` argument in a function signature when the function doesn't need to modify the string being passed in *may* allow the compiler to do optimizations it otherwise can't do.

Comment: In contradiction to your second point, I am not able to change the value at the addr pointed to by **const char* **.

`int main()
{
    const char* str = "Original string.";

    strcpy(str, "New string."); //error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]|

    return 0;
}`

Comment: @PankajKumarThapa That's only because you're pointing to a string literal. Try again with a `char` array.

Answer (score 29):

`const char *` means "pointer to an unmodifiable character." It's usually used for strings of characters that shouldn't be modified.

Say you're writing this function:

```
int checkForMatch(const char * pstr)
```

You've promised (through the function signature) that you *will not change* the thing pointed to by `pstr`. Now say part of checking for a match would involve ignore the case of letters, and you tried to do it by converting the string to upper case before doing your other checks:

```
strupr(pstr);
```

You'll get an error saying you can't do that, because `strupr` is declared as:

```
char * strupr(char* str);
```

...and that means it wants to be able to write to the string. You can't write to the characters in a `const char *` (that's what the `const` is for).

In general, you can pass a `char *` into something that expects a `const char *` without an explicit cast because that's a safe thing to do (give something modifiable to something that doesn't intend to modify it), but you *can't* pass a `const char *` into something expecting a `char *` (without an explicit cast) because that's not a safe thing to do (passing something that isn't meant to be modified into something that may modify it).

Of course, this is C, and you can do just about anything in C, including explicitly casting a `const char *` to a `char *` — but that would be a really, ***really bad idea*** because there is (presumably) some reason that the thing being pointed to by the pointer is `const`.

Comment: You can't write to the characters in a string literal, no matter how you declare the pointer.

Comment: @Neil: That's true. It would be one of the reasons why trying to would be a really bad idea. :-)

Comment: ...but let's get string literals out of it entirely -- updated.

Comment: The thing is I can understand the concept: const int nMyInt = 9;. It is like a #define. Though I cannot grasp the concept for char*.

Comment: @Sunscreen: A `char ch = 'A';` is a variable (`ch`) with a character you can change. So a `char *` is a *pointer* to a character you can change. In exactly the same way, a `const char ch = 'A';` is a variable (`ch`) for a character you *can't* change, and so a `const char *` is a *pointer* to a character you *can't* change (which usually means it's a pointer to a null-terminated string of them, although that's not necessarily the case).

Comment: @Neil, @Cowder you can't write to string literal for other reason than `const`, as said by you, and this means that indeed in general (from the language point of view) you __can__ write to string literal (e.g. on systems like there we are accustomed to, it's enough to be sure the string is not put in a read-only section)

Comment: @shin Both the C and C++ standards say that writing to  a literal will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Neil just since they can't force the system running C/C++ programs to a specific memory model (or to use a binary format with certain features)! If I know I can on my system and I disregard portability, then I can do it and it won't be "undefined behaviour" (from the stds point of view, I am writing non perfectly standard code however, of course; I am not saying it is a good practice, I wanted just to specify that it is not intrinsecally impossible)

Comment: @shin No matter what you do, from the standard's point of view it will ALWAYS be undefined behaviour. It may of course "work" for your particular implementation.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: To be safe doing that, you're better off with `char foo[] = "My string literal";` which initializes a char array with the *contents* of the string literal. You can then write to the array all you want; you're not writing to the string literal, you're writing to the array.

Comment: @Crowder I know it, but the 'topic' was "writing in a string literal", not in array! thanks anyway

Comment: @Neil if I can say that for the system Xyz doing so is ok, it means that for that system Xyz it is __not__ undefined behaviour. The standard has to say that since it can't address all the systems, as already said (and since I've already written it, and the fact that doing so you would not be perfectly standard compliant, what is the new  point of your comment?)

Comment: @shin You don't understand what is meant by "standard" or "undefined behaviour" - this conversation is now closed from my side.

Comment: @Neil u can't understand english(or my eng),nor logic,nor how faulty's assigning fixed meaning to words that have a general 1.I can't see which part u can't understand,&where it is in so annoying contrast with what u've already said and with the std to push u writing that;I've already said why std must say,that"feature"is undefined behaviour.-Nobody has forced u to discuss anything anyway,so no reason to specify anything - it looks more like shutting a door theatrically, things that histrions and stupids usually do.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: On tone: Let's try not to get into attacks, eh? On the facts: *"if I can say that for the system Xyz doing so is ok, it means that for that system Xyz it is **not** undefined behaviour..."* You can say that **if** the compiler you're using explicitly guarantees it in the documentation, yes. You **can't** say that if you've only demonstrated it empirically (the "works for me" test). You may have just got lucky, or the next minor bugfix version of the compiler might change it, etc., etc. I think that's what Neil was saying, I don't think it was meant to be mean or anything.

Comment: @Crowder I am suceptible, expecially when I am conversing relaxedly only for conversation's sake and someone says I don't understand and "close the conversation" explicitly,when to do so it is enough to not reply at all, so such a comment looks like an arrogant(fine) explanationless(not fine) attack. - It is not up to the compiler. If the system allows to modify literal strings (e.g. since has not a way of making a memory section read-only), there can't exist a single compiler implementation able to force a "segmentation fault". And the standard forces not a compilation-time check.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: I should probably step away from this as well, but again, there's a difference between what *works* and what's *defined*. There can be lots of things that work that are still undefined. Writing to memory that should, by the defined standard, not be writeable may *work*. That doesn't make it defined, just functional. It's still undefined behavior barring (again) the non-standard behavior being *documented*, which it could well be for certain classes of system (embedded ones, for instance).

Comment: @Crowder it is why I wrote that it is faulty `assigning fixed meaning to words that have a general 1`.Std can't say differently(or not all compilers on all sys are able to be std-compliant);does the std say «"str literal" _should_ be in RO mem?»Given a specific sys,the behaviour of that std-compliant code is _defined_ (the general meaning).`-std=c99 -pedantic` does not warn,so I interpret such a code as std-compliant.Since I know why I am using it and how it works on my sys,I obtain a defined behaviour,and disregard whatever the std has to say about.Functional in ur terminology.

Comment: Excellent explanation about passing char* even when its const char*

Answer (score 5):

- **char ***       : `non-constant` pointer to `non-constant` character
- **const char ***    : `non-constant` pointer to `constant`   character
- **char *const**     : `constant`   pointer to `non-constant` character
- **const char * const** : `constant`   pointer to `constant`   character

---

Reference [[link]](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-const-char-p-char-const-p-const-char-const-p/)

Answer (score 2):

I always try to define parameters with `const char*` not `char*` because converting from `std::string` to `conts char*` is easy by `.c_str()` method. However converting `std::string` to `char*` is not that easy.

Answer (score 1):

Probably I'm too picky. In my book, the character(s) pointed to by a const char* can possibly be changed but not via the const char*. A const char * can point to modifiable storage. Example:

```
char a[] = "abracadabra";
const char * ccp = &a[0]; // ccp points to modifiable storage.
*&a[0] = 'o'; // This writes to a location pointed to by const char* ccp
```

So, my wording is:

A char * is a pointer that be changed and that also allows writing through it when dereferenced via * or [].

A const char * is a pointer that be changed and that does not allow writing through it when dereferenced via * or [].

Comment: A `const char *` can also simply be cast to a normal `char *` to write to the address. This does NOT mean the write will succeed; for instance the pointer may point to non-writable memory. However, if writing to that address through any other means has well-defined behavior, then removing the const qualifier and writing that way also has well-defined behavior. It's useful for implementing functions like `strstr` which need to be able to handle both `char *` and `const char *` arguments while preserving non-const-ness in the returned pointer.

Comment: Exactly, the same thing also happens the other way around, where a legacy function has uses char* for read-only parameters and you trust it to not modify you (char*)-casted const char * pointers you give it as parameters.