# const char* vs char* (C++)

Tags: c++

For the following program:

```
int DivZero(int, int, int);

int main()
{
    try {
        cout << DivZero(1,0,2) << endl;
    }
    catch(char* e)
    {
        cout << "Exception is thrown!" << endl;
        cout << e << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int DivZero(int a, int b, int c)
{
    if( a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0)
        throw "All parameters must be greater than 0.";
    return b/c + a;
}
```

Using char* e will give

> terminate called after throwing an
>   instance of 'char const*'

According to [C++ Exception Handling](http://www.programmingforums.org/thread30610.html) , the solution is to use **const char*** instead.

Further reading from [function (const char *) vs. function (char *)](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/222695-function-const-char-vs-function-char#post911541) said that

> The type of "String" is `char*', not`
>   const char*'
>
> > (this is a C discussion I think...)

Additional reading on Stack Overflow [char* vs const char* as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179645/char-vs-const-char-as-a-parameter) tells me the difference. But none of them address my questions:

1. It seems like both **char*** and **string*** have limit on the numbers of characters. Am I correct?
2. How does adding the keyword *const* to **char*** eliminates that limit? I thought the only purpose of **const** is to set a flag that said "unmodifiable". I understand that **const char*** e means " the pointer which points to unmodifiable char type".

The solution to that error is to use ***const* char* e**.

Even const string* e doesn't work. (just for the sake of testing...)

Can anyone explain, please? Thank you!

By the way, I am on Ubuntu, compiled by GCC, on Eclipse.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why are you throwing and catching strings anyway?

You should throw and catch exceptions, e.g. [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error)

The answer to your question is that whenever you insert a string in quotes in the code it returns a null terminated const char*

The reason your code doesn't work as above is because it's the wrong type, so that catch, isn't catching what you're throwing. You're throwing a const char*.

There is no limit to the number of characters in a char array beyond the size of your stack/heap. If you're referring to the example you posted, that person had created a fixed size array, so they were limited.

Comment: @Salgar This is a sample code from the book Fundamental of Data Structure (2ed). So if I insert int [] it will return as const int* ????  (with the const keyword)?

Comment: Agreed, derive all exceptions from std::exception. throwing basic types leads to trouble. ensuring that everything derives from std::exception lets you be sure that `catch(std::exception e)` will catch everything. You want to reserve `catch(...)` for the most extreme cases, such as DLL boundaries. Throwing basic types often will lead to the need to `catch(...)` often.

use `throw std::runtime_error("All parameters must be greater than 0.");`

Comment: yes, lets you be sure that a catch(const std::exception& e) will catch everything.

Comment: @JongWong no, the type of the code "foo" is a const char*, the type of int[] is int[] and the type of int* is int*

Comment: I'm pretty sure a string literal has type `const char[N]`, with `N` being the string length+` (for the `'\0'`), not `const char*`, it just decays to that.

Answer (score 23):

The email you linked to about "String" is wrong (and confusing).

Basically:

`char*` is a pointer to an unbounded array of characters. Traditionally we consider such an array to be a C-string if it contains a set of valid characters followed by a `\0`. There's no limit to the size of the array.

`const char*` is a pointer to an unbounded array of *immutable* characters.

`string*` is a pointer to a `std::string` object, and is entirely different. This is a smart object that encapsulates a string. Using `std::string` instead of C-strings can make your life loads easier, even though they've got some rough edges and a lot of nasty gotchas; they're well worth looking into, but they're not relevant to the question.

`"String"` is a special expression that returns a `const char*` pointing at the specific C-string (note: this is not actually true, but it's a simplification that lets me answer the question concisely).

A `char*` can be automatically cast to a `const char*`, but not vice versa. Note that old C++ compilers had a special exception to the type rules to let you do this:

```
char* s = "String";
```

...without producing a type error; this was for C compatibility. Modern C++ compilers won't let you do it (such as recent gccs). They require this:

```
const char* s = "String";
```

So. The problem here is that you've got:

```
throw "All parameters must be greater than 0.";
```

...but then you're trying to catch it with:

```
catch(char* e)
```

This doesn't work, because the throw is throwing a `const char*`, which can't be cast to the type specified in the catch, so it isn't getting caught.

This is why changing the catch to:

```
catch (const char* e)
```

...makes it work.

Comment: +1, but every compiler I know of (including recent GCCs) lets you do `char* s = "String";` without error. Some may give a _warning_, on the other hand... ([Demo](http://ideone.com/xDb7L))

Comment: Well explained. I wish I can mark everyone, but I can't. He answered before you did. That's okay I guess. Your explanation was very helpful. I really like it. Thanks, David. I actually have found more on const.... wiki article called "const-correctness".  :]

Comment: @ildjarn +1 for your great comment and demo. :]

Comment: @JohnWong Glad to be of help (the sweet, sweet reputation points are nice too, muhahaha). Const correctness is well worth learning about; C++ is a very picky and extremely subtle language, and getting const correctness right may be a pain in the arse at times but will be hugely helpful when saving you from shooting your foot off later. C++ is not my favourite language...