# Code calls terminate instead of throwing exception

Tags: c++, exception, ubuntu-12.04, terminate

I want to throw an exception like this:

```
if (...) {  
    throw "not found";  
}
```

and catch it like this:

```
try {  
    myfunction();  
} catch (const char * msg) {  
    cout << msg << endl;  
}
```

but then it says

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
```

Why does it call terminate and not throw my "not found"?

EDIT:

I changed it to this:

```
try {
    throw "not found";
} catch (const char * msg) {
    cout << "test" << endl;
} catch(...) {
    cout << "test" << endl;
}
```

and I get the same error!

EDIT2:
When I don't call a specific method above, it works! But I don't understand what this method has to do with exceptions, I didn't use it in any other function than the above mentioned myfunction(). Let me test some more and then I will get back to you!

EDIT3:

Oh my, this is embarrassing. Looks like I called the wrong function. I am so so sorry to have bothered you with this shameful experience!

Comment: @ta.speot.is: What is not what?

Comment: @BastianMattes: can you show your real code?

Comment: Use a debugger to find out

Comment: Sorry guys, I saw the `const` wasn't in the same place and got confused by `const` vs `const *` vs whatever Scott Meyers talks about knowing the difference between.

Comment: please post a complete small example

Comment: @BastianMattes http://liveworkspace.org/code/3Z0gVd$8 <- works for me.  Are you possibly calling `myfunction()` outisde of a `try` block before you even reach your `try`?

Comment: I think your if (...) is the thrower not your `throw "not found"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208565/const-char-vs-char-c looks like you're probably doing catch(char* msg) but are telling us that you're doing catch(const char* msg)

Comment: Sorry for not answering sooner, somehow I never got an email that this questions got answered.

Comment: @AndyProwl: This is now my real code. (@Cheers and hth. - Alf)

Comment: sidenote: You should always use exceptions derived (directly or indirectly) from `std::exception`, so that your clients can at least catch upon that.

Comment: @us2012,@thiagoh,@thang: No, see my edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use throw outside of a try/catch block, terminate gets called. Make sure the function that throws is in the try block.

```
#include <iostream>

void myFunc()
{
    throw "Throwing!";
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        myFunc();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Works fine.";
    }

    myFunc(); // Terminate gets called.

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: See my edit above, I am definitely throwing inside the try block.